# Truncate Decimal value

Tags: python, decimal

I have the following Python `Decimal` variable:

```
mydecimal = Decimal('1.452300')
```

And the following resolution variable:

```
resolution = Decimal('0.0001')
```

How could I get the variable truncated to the `resolution` value using just those two variables (which is the information I will have in my actual routine):

```
# Desired result:
truncated_mydecimal = Decimal('1.4523')  # <-- How do I get this using 'resolution' and 'mydecimal' ?
```

Comment: Your question is not quite clear since you do not explain just what your "resolution variable" is. Is it guaranteed to be a power of ten? Do you want the result to have the same number of decimal places as `resolution`?

Comment: resolution has 4 decimal places and hence truncated_mydecimal will be mydecimal with just 4 decimal places. But resolution might be 0.0005, in that case, again 4 decimal places would be desired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what the [`quantize()`](https://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize) method is for:

```
>>> mydecimal.quantize(resolution)
Decimal('1.4523')
```

Read the docs, or do

```
>>> help(mydecimal.quantize)
```

for more.  Caution:  the precise value of your `resolution` variable doesn't matter - it's the internal exponent `quantize()` cares about.  For example, nothing about the output above would change had we done:

```
>>> resolution = Decimal('0.0009')
```

instead.